# How to get Ip address of other devices connected to switch network via Wifi programmatically?

Tags: java, android, ip-address, printers

In my project I need to get the ip address of the two different network that is connected to the switch for example my device ip is 192.168.2.5 and my printer ip address is 10.1.7.5

I need to detect the printer ip address from my devices programmatically in android.

Comment: guys please give me any suggest on this (coding r lib if available)

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 ways of solving your problem:

1) Your printer must register it IPv4 address somewhere. For example, in dynamic DNS zone with a predefined name. Then you can lookup this name there and get it IP addr.

2) If your switch is smart enough (eg, is manageable one), You can login into it interface (ssh or web) and scan through MAC address table. In this case you must know printer MAC to look for.

Comment: k i'll try it but for scanning single network printer is it working fine but when i used the switch connected to other network it is not working  is there any lib for it to get it?

Comment: There are no such libs.

The problem is that you don't understand enough how TCP\IP works. Please educate yourself.